# web service for finding location information using PIN code (India)

Tags: web-services, location, info

I am working on a *restaurant meal ordering system*.

I need a *web service* that gives information of a location, given the area PINcode.

PINcode? *wikipedia:* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_Index_Number

> A Postal Index Number or **PIN** or **Pincode** is a code in the post office numbering or post code system used by India Post, the Indian postal administration. The code is six digits long.

Answer (score 0):

Google Geocoding API and places API can be used for your purpose

Comment: won't do it.. [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)